# Why does a simple numerical filter slow way down in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

This Erlang script prints out odd numbers starting at 3.
The script gets progressively slower as it runs. The idea was to somehow build on this to make something similar to the sieve example for Go, but it's already too slow even while filtering out only the even numbers. What causes the slowdown and how can it be fixed?

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript

main(_) ->
  print_nums().

generate(From) ->
  generate(From, 2).

generate(From, N) ->
  From ! N,
  generate(From, N+1).

filter(Caller, P) ->
  receive
    N -> case (N rem P) of
          0 -> filter(Caller, P);
          _ -> Caller ! N,
               filter(Caller, P)
         end
  end.

print_nums() ->
  Self = self(),
  FilterPid = spawn(fun() -> filter(Self, 2) end),
  spawn(fun() -> generate(FilterPid) end),
  print_nums_loop().

print_nums_loop() ->
  receive
    N -> io:format("~p~n", [N])
  end,
  print_nums_loop().
```

Comment: I run it, at the first, the ouput is quicky, and then become slower

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply because your producer `generate` produces messages more quickly than the consumer `filter` can consume. It's the standard boring [producer-consumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) problem :-)

Run this slightly modified version of your script which prints out the message queue in the filter process every 500 messages received by the filter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
%% -*- mode: erlang -*-
%%! -smp enable -hidden

main(_) ->
    Self = self(),
    FilterPid = spawn(fun() -> filter(Self, 2) end),
    spawn(fun() -> generate(FilterPid) end),
    main_loop().

main_loop() ->
    receive
        N -> io:format("~B~n", [N])
    end,
    main_loop().

filter(Caller, P) ->
    receive
        N when N rem P =:= 0 -> ok;
        N -> Caller ! N
    end,
    if N rem 500 =:= 0 -> print_queue_len();
       true -> ok
    end,
    filter(Caller, P).

print_queue_len() ->
    {message_queue_len, Len} = erlang:process_info(self(), message_queue_len),
    io:format("Len:~B~n", [Len]).

generate(Filter) ->
    generate(Filter, 2).

generate(Filter, N) ->
    Filter ! N,
    generate(Filter, N+1).
```

The message queue grows very quickly, which slows the filter down even more with every message received. You need to let the consumer control how quickly the generator produces messages (introduce [flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_control_%28data%29)). Like in this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
%% -*- mode: erlang -*-
%%! -smp enable -hidden

main(_) ->
    Self = self(),
    FilterPid = spawn(fun() -> filter(Self, 2) end),
    spawn(fun() -> generate(FilterPid) end),
    main_loop().

main_loop() ->
    receive
        N -> io:format("~B~n", [N])
    end,
    main_loop().

filter(Caller, P) ->
    receive
        {Pid, N} when N rem P =:= 0 -> ok;
        {Pid, N} -> Caller ! N
    end,
    Pid ! ok,
    filter(Caller, P).

generate(Filter) ->
    generate(Filter, 2).

generate(Filter, N) ->
    Filter ! {self(), N},
    receive
        ok -> generate(Filter, N+1)
    end.
```

Comment: This works. Thank you! This is very different from the Go approach of just having limit on the number of messages in a channel.

Comment: Message passing is truly asynchronous in Erlang. It's a design decision. If the VM tried to suspend a process after the process received N messages then it could cause a deadlock if another process was to rely on receiving a response (which would be the N+1 message in the queue and wouldn't be accepted by the VM). I recommend to you Joe Armstrong's PHD thesis where he explains the design decisions he had to make when developing Erlang: http://ftp.nsysu.edu.tw/FreeBSD/ports/distfiles/erlang/armstrong_thesis_2003.pdf

Comment: So this is why deadlocks are more common when using Go but I've never seen them in Erlang.

Comment: It's certainly possible to encounter a deadlock in Erlang. See this paper which discusses two possible scenarios and ways of detecting it statically: http://research.microsoft.com/en-US/people/mchri/tfp-2011.pdf
However, as certainly, because of the design decisions, they are much less common (if not of different type) than in other languages.

Comment: Here's the working translation of the Go prime sieve, thanks to your help: https://gist.github.com/ijt/39a0c22cb369da7c04b6